# Unable to copy symbols from this device XCode 4.6.3

Tags: ios, xcode

i just upgraded my XCode to latest 4.6.3. My iPad is running on iOS 6.1.3 Build (10B329).

When i connect my iPad this Message is shown in the organizer Window and i'm not able to select the device in XCode Main Window.
I already tried to delete the device support directory for this version or set permissions. 
But Nothing worked so far.

Unable to copy symbols from this device.
This device has a version of iOS different from that of this installation of Xcode.
In order to copy the information needed to work with this device, Xcode must be run by a user with read/write access to:
“/Users/USER/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/6.1.3 (10B329)/Symbols//usr/lib/dyld”

Am i something missing?

Comment: Do you have read/write access to the folder it specifies? Does it even exist?

Comment: Yes it exists and permissions are correct. What else can i do?

Answer (score 18):

Is the hard drive on your Mac full?  When I got this same message, using iOS 7 and Xcode 5, that was my problem. I'd filled my hard drive so Xcode couldn't copy the large symbols file to said folder.

Once I made more space, the operation worked without error.

Comment: doesn't work for me. i have the same issues with an iPadAir and xcode6.4. I have the right permissions and the space on the device